# How to change UI after firebase cloud function execution?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I followed up this article to send email from angular website.
https://medium.com/@markgoho/create-a-contact-form-in-angular-using-cloud-functions-for-firebase-5e390bdf5600
The emails are being sent nicely. However, I am facing issues on how to update UI when the cloud function successfully completes and when it has error, like a message saying "Email was sent". Or change color of the send button to Green. 
Does firebase function has anything for UI because I cannot find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to write the result of the Cloud Function (e.g. success or error) to the message document in your Real Time Database (i.e. under `messages/{pushKey}`) and listen to changes to this database node in your app, with a listener.

In the Cloud Function you would do along these lines:

```
exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushKey}').onWrite((data, context) => {
  const snapshot = change.after;
  const pushKey = context.params.pushKey;

  .....

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
  .then(() => {
     const update = {};
     updates['/messages/' + pushKey + '/status'] = 'success';
     return admin
       .database()
       .ref()
       .update(update);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     const update = {};
     updates['/messages/' + pushKey + '/status'] = 'failure';
     return admin
       .database()
       .ref()
       .update(update);
  })
```

Note that I have adpated the Cloud Function syntax to the new version, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Note that, with version >= 1.0 you have to initialize the Function as:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: That is a really clever solution. I haven't tried it yet, but seems like a good way.

Comment: @AyushGupta Hi, did you have time to give a try?

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks :)